# WordPress Site Ignoring @import Statement

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Unsure what has happened with the site layout but from what I can see, within the `style.css` file, right at the top of the file, the following two lines:

```
@import "css/reset.css";
@import "css/layout.css";
```

are not being called or ignored.

The funny thing is, is that this used to work fine but no longer does as no changes have been made to the site since mid 2012.

The WordPress site is: http://solarinstallations.com.au/

Any ideas why the `import css/layout.css` is being ignored within the `style.css` file as I can't see what it might be.

Comment: It *is* importing those styles...Verified using Chrome's inspector. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Reason is b/c the styles within layout.css no longer seem to be used and so the site is all out of whack.

Comment: Look in your network tab. reset and layout ***are*** being used. you have css errors in dev tools. it possible either an error in those files is causing the css to not render or the styles set  therein are being overwritten

Comment: Removed all the errors from style.css alone and unfortunately layout.css is being ignored. For example not even this style is being used from layout.css, i.e. #page1 .row-1 .col-1 {width: 241px; padding: 0 5px 0 0;} and unsure why it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate people's comments/assistance. In the end, I found that there was nothing actually wrong with the stylesheet in question but actually a corrupted header.php file.

Simply replaced it with a copy I had backed up a while ago and now all is fine again.